# Como criar alguma especie de "index dinamico" no banco de dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem, classificação, otimização

Eu tenho uma tabela com 10000 registros, mas aqui vou representar com apenas 10 deles.

```
+-------+---------+------------------+
| index | posicao |      nome        |
+-------+---------+------------------+
|     1 |       0 |    arquivo 1.mp3 |
|     2 |       1 |    arquivo 2.mp3 |
|     3 |       2 |    arquivo 3.mp3 |
|     4 |       3 |    arquivo 4.mp3 |
|     5 |       4 |    arquivo 5.mp3 |
|     6 |       5 |    arquivo 6.mp3 |
|     7 |       6 |    arquivo 7.mp3 |
|     8 |       7 |    arquivo 8.mp3 |
|     9 |       8 |    arquivo 9.mp3 |
+-------+---------+------------------+
```

Porém ao adicionar um registro ali no meio, eu preciso que a tabela toda se atualize para entender suas novas `posições`.

```
+-------+---------+-------------------+
| index | posicao |       nome        |
+-------+---------+-------------------+
|     1 |       0 |    arquivo 1.mp3  |
|     2 |       1 |    arquivo 2.mp3  |
|     3 |       2 |    arquivo 3.mp3  |
|    10 |       3 |    arquivo 70.mp3 | < --- novo registro
|     4 |       4 |    arquivo 4.mp3  |
|     5 |       5 |    arquivo 5.mp3  |
|     6 |       6 |    arquivo 6.mp3  |
|     7 |       7 |    arquivo 7.mp3  |
|     8 |       8 |    arquivo 8.mp3  |
|     9 |       9 |    arquivo 9.mp3  |
+-------+---------+-------------------+
```

Pode ver que o `arquivo 4.mp3` que antes estava na `posição 3`, agora mudou para a `posição 4`, e todos a sua frente também.
O problema é que atualizar milhares de registros não viável para mim, como eu poderia fazer com que cada registro soubesse sua devia posição sem ter que atualizar cada um individualmente ?

Comment: Da uma olhada no Elastic Search https://www.elastic.co/pt/products/elastic-stack

Comment: "como eu poderia fazer com que cada registro soubesse sua devida posição sem ter que atualizar cada um individualmente", pois é, como ele poderia saber sua devida posição sem você informar? Veja seu exemplo, qual o motivo do registro ter que estar na posição 3 e não na sétima (se for uma classificação simples pelo nome) ou décima (se for o último inserido ou o classificado pelo número do arquivo)?

Comment: Alguma resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Answer (score 3):

Não precisa e não existe isso de "índice dinâmico", todos os índices são dinâmicos por natureza, eles se atualizam quando você tem uma informação que o afete.

O que precisa é mudar a tabela mesmo, do jeito que descreveu, não existe milagre, existe uma lei da física que impede as coisas mudarem sozinhas. Poderia até ter algum recurso no banco de dados que faria sozinho para você, mas as atualizações na tabela ocorreriam da mesma forma, e justamente porque não haveria ganho real e provocaria uma ilusão, é até bom que não tenha algo assim. Se o seu problema é mudar os dados você terá que mudar os dados.

Qual o motivo que inviabiliza alterar milhares de linhas? Diz que tem uma tabela com 10 mil linhas, esta é uma das menores tabelas que já vi, ainda mais se tiver só essas 3 colunas. Inclusive pra achar o dado fará quase o mesmo que tem que fazer para mudar esses dados, claro que a escrita custa mais caro, mas não é o fim do mundo.

A resposta do Michel Simões dá o SQL que você provavelmente já faria e altera milhares de linhas, ou seja, ela não responde de fato o que perguntou.

Sem entender o problema exato nem podemos oferecer uma solução alternativa, a gente nem sabe porque existe uma coluna `index` e uma `posicao`, talvez nem deveria ter ambas, talavez sim, para ter um `id` estável, ma não sabemos.

Se você puder reformular isso poderia ter uma coluna `posicao` e, sei lá, uma coluna `desempate`, aí você não mexe mais em `posicao` e por padrão o `desempate` entra sempre como valor `0`, e se entrar um logo depois dele entra como `1`, e se tiver outro depois desse a `posicao` fica a mesma e o `desempate` entra como `2`, e assim por diante.

Claro, se tiver muito isso, em última análise, pode acabar tendo todas `posicao` iguais e o `desempate` virar o que era a `posicao`, mas aí pode ter uma rotina que normalize isso e quando rodá-la ela irá refazer só uma vez renumerando todas `posicao` e zerando o `desempate`, assim resolve.

Se você tiver que inserir no meio dessa lista de desempate terá que alterar os valores de `desempate`, mas, se não acontecer o que eu falei no parágrafo anterior, será uma quantidade bem menor de linhas para alterar e a normalização de posições que eu citei fará com que isso não seja necessário, é uma das técnicas mais famosas da computação, o dividir para conquistar.

Porém isso é complicação demais e só seria interessante se essa inserção ocorre várias vezes por segundo, o que eu duvido. Faz o simples, eu duvido que tem um problema real aí, apenas tem algo que não quer fazer por achar que é ruim, sem nenhum fundamento. Caso contrário a pergunta não dá informações suficientes para ajudá-lo melhor. Se não souber fazer certo aquilo será pior que a atualização pura e simples.

Se tiver um problema real de performance eu faria uma série de testes de alternativas para resolver, tem uma infinidade de possibilidades, mas para isso precisa ter duas características: entender muito bem o funcionamento de um banco de dados e aspectos gerais da computação, incluindo aspectos matemáticos, coisa que poucas pessoas querem estudar; e ao mesmo tempo entender muito bem o problema em detalhes. Eu não sei sobre uma delas (e se soubesse levaria horas ou dias para chegar a um resultado, que pode ser inclusive que a melhor forma é o que já está fazendo) e você não sabe a outra, por isso fica difícil dar uma solução.

Answer (score 0):

Ola, Lucas!
Tentei reproduzir o problema e realmente é mais complexo do que realmente parece. Uma alternativa ao seu problema seria simplificar o SQL...
Desta forma, voce faz o que gostaria de forma ao menos 'elegante'

> update TABELA set ordem = ordem + 1 where ordem > 3 (para acrescentar
>   1 para os itens acima da nova ordem)

e assim a posição 3 ficaria livre para você inserir o registro 10 e todos subiriam 1.

Comment: Consegue fazer uma tabela de exemplo ?

Comment: Consigo, deixa só eu ter um minuto aqui hoje que faço pra vc. Boa sorte ai man!!

Comment: @LucasCarezia da uma olhada na resposta, se te atende...